# regex opposite of exact phrase (openwebmail)

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need to find all emails aren't `info@example.com` to config `openwebmail` with regex

With result:

```
abbb@example.com --  true

76312783dd@example.com -- true

8734289347@test.it -- true

info@example.com -- false
```

Comment: `^(?!info@example\.com$)\w+@\w+\.\w+$`

Answer (score 0):

This would be my answer:

```
^(?!info@example\.com$)((\w+|\.)+@\w+(\.\w+)+)$
```

This will match everything in your examples except `info@example.com`, and a few more that would be useful, such as `test.example@mail.co.uk`, as shown in the example here:

[Click here for the example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mR4wJ6/1)

**Edit**

You could also change the regex to:

```
 ^(?!info@example\.com$)((\w+\.?)+@\w+(\.\w+)+)$
```

To disallow the emails: `info..example@mail.com`, but as you are simply searching through emails, it is very unlikely that you will come across an email with the format `info..example@mail.com`

**Breakdown**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!)` Negative lookahead
- `info@example\.com$` Literal match of info.example.com, and it being until the end of the string.
- `(\w+|\.)+` Capture group with letters and numbers 1 or more times, or a dot, 1 or more times *Will match `example..test@mail.com`*
- `(\w\.?)+` Capture group with letters 1 or more times, with a following optional dot, 1 or more times. *Will not match `example..test@mail.com`*
- `@\w+` Matches `@` literally, and any letters or numbers after.
- (.\w+)+ Matches a dot and any letters coming after it 1 or more times. Dot not optional because an email like: `example@test.com.` is invalid.
- `$` End of string

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work on openwebmail. Alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Use this **great trick!**:

```
^info@example\.com$|^(\w+@\w+\.\w+)$
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/zJ5nY5/1

### Explanation:

1. `a|b|(c|d)` and take the group 1 value. This is one of the most popular regex trick ever. This way, if you take group 1 value, `a` and `b` will be automatically ignored and you only approve `c` and `d`.
2. `\w` is any character that we normally find inside a word.